# Как проверить авторизирован ли пользователь? Django

Tags: python, django

Как проверить авторизирован ли пользователь в шаблоне `base.html`. Уже все перепробовал и `user.is_authenticated` и `request.user.is_authenticated` ничего не работает

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, который у вас не работает и описание того, что именно происходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте, что у вас подключены все MIDDLEWARE, касающиеся пользователей. Подсмотреть можно в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated), а проверить путем вывода `{{ user }}` в шаблоне

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
  AUTHED
{% else %}
  GUEST
{% endif %}
```

[django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated)

Comment: Про какие именно MIDDLEWARE вы говорите?

Comment: `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` уже подключен

Comment: Решил проблему, оказывается я рендерил шаблоны `render_to_response`

Answer (score 2):

Если пользуетесь `TemplateView`, то можно так переопределить базовый метод:

```py
class ProfilePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home_user_page.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated == True:
            # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
            # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
            # request method isn't on the approved list.
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
            return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return redirect("login")
```